# How to show that $1, 2, 3$ are the only numbers which are both Fibonacci and Lucas without using the Primitive Divisor Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

In the following [preprint](http://diego.mat.unb.br/doc/orderFmpm1.pdf) by Diego Marques, titled "The order of appearance of integers at most one away from Fibonacci numbers", it is claimed that (on page $11$):

> It is a simple matter to deduce from *Primitive Divisor Theorem* that $1, 2$ and $3$ are the only integers which are both [Fibonacci](http://oeis.org/A000045) and [Lucas](http://oeis.org/A000032) numbers.

I tried searching for the keyword "Primitive Divisor Theorem" and found out that it was proved (in its simplest form) by Bilu, Hanrot, and Voutier.

Here is my question:

> How can I show that $1, 2$ and $3$ are the only numbers which are both Fibonacci and Lucas without using the Primitive Divisor Theorem?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Using Binet's formulas seem to be out of the question.

Alas, this is where I get stuck!

Comment: So you only tried Binet's formula? How about some simple relations between Lucas numbers and Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @Sil This is in fact the most obvious approach and almost immediately leads to the desired proof.

Comment: @Peter Your answer seems like the simplest way to handle this (and $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$ is the very first relation on the article about Lucas numbers, that's why I asked about the attempt, Binet's formula is usually a way to make the problem more complicated). By the way I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28001, guess we could make this a duplicate, but your answer would be nice to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim : For every $n\ge 3$ , we have $$F_{n+1}<L_n<F_{n+2}$$ This implies that no Lucas number greater than $3$ can also be a Fibonacci-number. The first inequality immediately follows from $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$

So, it remains to show $F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}<F_{n+2}$ , but this is equivalent to $F_{n-1}<F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}$ hence equivlant to $F_{n-1}<F_n$ which clearly holds for $n\ge 3$